# How to work out an Excel formula to pick up the lowest price for each category?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula in Excel where I can select certain entries to be posted in another sheet or table. So basically what I have here is a tender for digital devices: computers, laptops mainframe, and there is 4 companies that applied for the tender so after the technical and commercial study of the tender offers there is companies that passed in certain items and failed in others.

So I put the unit price in USD for each company for the items and I am trying to create a formula to pick up the lowest price for each company BUT with the condition that it should be labeled PASSED not failed so I can make the report with the lowest passed companies for each item with their company name.

I tried using minimum and match and index but that got me the lowest price including the failed companies so I don't know what to do I attached a copy of the dummy excel sheet for you to check it out and help me.

[Dummy Excel sheet](https://www.mediafire.com/?y68znv3odk10wri)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in O4:

```
=MIN(IF(E4:K4="passed",F4:L4))
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, and in N4:

```
=INDEX(F$2:L$2,MATCH(O4,F4:L4,0))
```

with both formulae copied down to suit.